# What does StackApplet "Network Error" mean?

Tags: chromium, proxy, localhost, stackapplet, socks5

I just installed StackApplet StackApplet 1.5 using the debian package from the launchpad site. When I first clicked on the preferences button in the menu it tried opening `http://localhost:8150/` in Chromium, and I got this error:

```
This webpage is not available The webpage at http://localhost:8150/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 120 (net::ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED): Unknown error.
```

My Chromium is launched with a switch to make it use a socks5 proxy, using this command:

```
chromium-browser  --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:1080" %U
```

I remembered that I wasn't using a bypass proxy URL list so I added the switch: `--proxy-bypass-list="localhost,127.0.0.1"` to the above command and I was then able to access the preference page without any problems.

However, after adding my account information I see the message: `Network Error.` in the StackApplet menu.  This makes me think that StackApplet might be trying to use the socks5 proxy--even though it is not set globally, only Chromium uses this proxy. I don't require StacksApplet to use my proxy, in fact it would probably be better if it didn't.  So my questions are:

1. What does the `Network Error.` message mean?
   and
2. What should I do to fix/debug this error?

Comment: This looks like a bug in the package. Please contact the author and report it.

Comment: Close voters: This is not necessarily a bug, and George Edison has posted a general answer that should help others. I recommend against closing this (at least so far).

Answer (score 2):

I am the author of StackApplet and I'll do my best to answer your question.

> "...so I added the switch: `--proxy-bypass-list="localhost,127.0.0.1"` to the above command and I was then able to access the preference page without any problems."

I'm actually surprised that Chromium wouldn't display a local URL without the command-line argument specifying a proxy. Still - if it works, that's great.

> "What does the Network Error. message mean?"

This error is displayed whenever the application receives [a `URLError` exception](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.URLError) from the urllib2 Python module. This can happen for a number of different reasons - including a misconfigured proxy.

> "What should I do to fix/debug this error?"

This is tricky.

StackApplet isn't able to use either system-wide or Chromium-specific proxy settings. (In fact, being able to configure proxy settings for StackApplet has been a long-standing feature request.)

What I would suggest is running StackApplet in a terminal. Make sure that all running instances of the application are closed and run:

```
/usr/bin/stackapplet
```

Keep an eye out for any error messages that appear in the output.

If you continue to receive errors, please file a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/stackapplet).